# Django models: Parent model accessing child model field

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL    

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')

class Tutor(UserProfile):
   # tutor_fields here
```

From User object how can I access Tutor? is it with `user.profile`?

`user.profile.select_related('tutor')` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OneToOneField` work like `ForeignKey` except `unique=True` and you don't need to specify the `related_name` (you can specify if you want to change it).

For you example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL    

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')

class Tutor(UserProfile):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tutor')
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

NB: Use a `ForeignKey` if you want/need one `Tutor` for many `UserProfile`, else if you want one (and only one) `Tutor` for one `UserProfile`

And you can access to the `Tutor` bu `UserProfile` by `UserProfile.tutor.details`.

Answer (score 0):

As described [in the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/), you should be able to access it with `user.user_profile`.